# Angular - InjectionToken with Parameter

Tags: angular, angular-injector, injection-tokens

I have an `InjectionToken` like:

```
export const SOURCE_DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN =
    new InjectionToken<CustomObject[]>('All Source Data', {
      providedIn: 'root',
      factory: () => {
        // Returns all source
        return someArrayData // This data is read from a local .json file;
      }
    });
```

And my component uses it directly as it should,

```
@Component({})
export class SourceManager {
  sourceDataList: CustomObject[] = inject(SOURCE_DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN);
}
```

Now, I have to upgrade my INJECTION_TOKEN to return data based on the source selected by the user in Component. Updates in the component will look like this:

```
@Component({})
export class SourceManager {
  selectedSource: SourceEnum = SourceEnum.SomeSource1

  sourceDataList: CustomObject[] = inject(SOURCE_DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN);
}
```

This `selectedSource` can be changed from UI. I want to send this `selectedSource` enum to my injection token and instead of returning all sources, now the token will be returning filtered data.

I see factory method can have parameter as well, can I somehow pass `selectedSource` to it?

Comment: but why don't you use a service instead of token injection?

Comment: @Chris I know `Service` can easily overcome this. And service will result in a lot of code refactoring, I hope this can be done by modifying the current implementation.

Comment: Why not filtering the `sourceDataList` after injecting the complete list into it?

Comment: @derstauner This is not exactly my use case. I just refined it for SO. Consider loading data from different JSON file based on `selectedSource`. Every source has a specific JSON file to load data.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing SOURCE_DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN into observable you do not have too many options, unfortunately. Right now I can think only about this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-easguk?file=src%2Fmain.ts

```
type Datum = {
  id: string;
};
export const SOURCE_ADD_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Subject<Datum>>(
  'Add Source',
  {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => new Subject<Datum>(),
  }
);

export const SOURCE_DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Datum[]>(
  'All Source Data',
  {
    providedIn: 'root',
    factory: () => {
      let items = [{ id: '0' }];
      inject(SOURCE_ADD_TOKEN).subscribe((newItem) => {
        items.push(newItem);
      });
      return items;
    },
  }
);

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
     We have {{data.length}} item(s)
     <button (click)="onChangeClick()">Add</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public data = inject(SOURCE_DATA_INJECTION_TOKEN);

  private add$ = inject(SOURCE_ADD_TOKEN);

  onChangeClick() {
    this.add$.next({ id: nanoid() });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working, even Stackbliz example is not working, data.length is always 1.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to hit Save, re-check same URL

Comment: This works if I push item to same array, but in my case I have update data every time, so your line `items.push(newItem);` will be `items = [newItem];` in my case. This doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, assigning new variable will require to modify token to be observable, unfortunately

Comment: Another option for you will be to use signals, of course

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Signals do seems like a good approach.